# ggplot2 for grayscale printouts

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 produces fancy graphs for screen/color prints, but the gray background and the colors interfere when printing them to grayscale. For better readablility, I'd prefer to disable the gray background and use color generators that produce either different shades of gray or different kinds of filling strokes to distinguish the groups.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

** EDIT ** Updated code: `geom_bar` requires a `stat`.

`theme_bw` could be what you're after. If you are plotting a geom that has a fill such as bars, the `scale_fill_grey` function will give you control over the shades of grey. If you are plotting a geom that has a colour (such as a line or points), the `scale_colour_grey` function will give you the control. As far as I know, ggplot does not plot patterned fills. Assuming you're plotting bars, the following will plot coloured bars on a grey background.

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.table(text = 
"type Year  Value 
 A    2000  3
 B    2000  10
 C    2000  11
 A    2001  4
 B    2001  5
 C    2001  12", sep = "", header = TRUE)

(p = ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value)) +       
  geom_bar(aes(fill = type), stat="identity", position = "dodge"))
```

The following changes the coloured bars to shades of grey. Note that one of the bars gets lost in the background.

```
(p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9))
```

The following removes the grey background.

```
(p = p + theme_bw())
```

[image]

A point has a colour, not a fill. So to use shades of grey on points, you would need something like this.

```
(p = ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value)) +       
  geom_point(aes(colour = type), size = 5) +
  scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = .9) +
  theme_bw())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The others answerers have focused on adjusting the line/bar colors automatically. In a print publication, however, I'd prefer not to have light gray lines etc. since they are difficult to recognize and distinguish. Here's a solution that adjusts the line type automatically (which I wasn't aware was possible until a day ago).

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

data <- read.table(text = 
"type Year  Value 
 A    1998  6
 A    1999  8
 A    2000  6
 A    2001  7
 B    1998  4
 B    1999  5
 B    2000  10
 B    2001  5
 C    1998  8
 C    1999  6
 C    2000  9
 C    2001  8", sep = "", header = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(data=data,
            aes(x = factor(Year),
                y = Value,
                linetype = factor(type)))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(group = factor(type)),
                   size=0.8)
```

[image]

Note that you can [easily customize ggplot themes](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/11/20/formatting-plots-for-pubs.html).
Here's an alternative result using [my own minimalistic ggplot theme](https://github.com/gonike/rrelated/blob/master/ep_theme.r):

[image]

(Antialiasing looks way better when exported to pdf than it does here [in png].)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of what you want

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.table(text = 
  "Letter      Year    Value 
 A           1998    5
                B           1999    10
                C           2000    15
                A           2000    7
                B           2001    15
                C           2002    20", sep = "", header = TRUE)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value, colour = Letter)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = Letter)) + scale_colour_grey() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'))
```

[image]