# How do i add grey scale color palette in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a grey scale version of my bar plot for color blind readers.
I have used the code below. How do I modify the code given I am content with the rest of the plot as is?

[image]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=PSP,fill=factor(DECAY)))+
  geom_bar(width=0.5)+facet_wrap(~SU)+xlab("Sampling Unit (SU)")+ylab("Count")+
  labs(fill="LEVEL OF DECAY")+ggtitle("Breakdown of decay per principle sample plot (PSP)")+
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("0", "0.5", "1", "2", "3"),
                      labels=c("None (Healthy)", "Decay of crown", "Recently dead",
                               "Advanced decay","Standing snags"))
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501217/ggplot2-for-grayscale-printouts#13507514) help? You did not link any image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about replacing `scale_fill_discrete(...)` with `scale_fill_grey(...)` ?

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_grey.html